# Android Virtual Device Basic Settings List?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Does any body know i there is any site with a complete list of devices (Samsung, Kindle, Nexus, ...)  and their settings to config the AVD?

Thanks!

Juan Carlos

Comment: The newest version of Android SDK already come with a lot of configurations you'll need.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the last version of Android SDK, there is Device Definition section. There, you can find a list of devices android, with their settings

Comment: The last version at now, is 21

Comment: But there I can't see Kindle or Samsungs devices...

Comment: Ok, but if you use a sample device, with the same display size, then you search the device's specific you can change the other settings to your device and so on..
I think it's the only solution

Comment: The initial question was this: if there is any web with a list of the device's specific... so for the Samsung models are this, for Nexus this...